# align left and right with float: works in FF/IE but not in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

I'm using this

```
.align-left {
   float: left;
   width: 49%;
   }
.align-right {
   float: right;
   width: 49%;
   text-align: right; /* depends on element width */
   }
```

With this html:

```
<span class="align-left">this shows to the left<span><span class="align-right">this to the right<span>
```

And it works fine in IE/FF but not in Chrome? I'm no CSS expert but I'd like to avoid using tables, any suggestions?

Comment: You already have an answer here and seem to have solved it - but I wanted to point out something additional. You will often have issues with narrow rendering scenarios when you use `float: left; width: 49%;` and `float: right; width: 49%;` - which comes from the fact that `%`-based sizing like this blows up with borders and margins which expand the width. Also - if your items get small enough that `%`'s start becoming partial-pixels - you'll have trouble. Consider, instead, `display: table-cell;` and/or `box-sizing: border-box;` to avoid this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close your span tags and it will work.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/ESQE7/

Comment: `display:none`? what about `display:block`?

Comment: Floating spans is fine, a span is used (without display:block;) in the CSS2 specs as an example floating element: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats

Comment: I think the problem may be that I actually have a <form> element within that second <span>, which works ok in the other browsers but not in Chrome? Using divs now, which works fine. Thanks!

Comment: ps: I had my span tags closed, just typed the code badly here.

Comment: If switching from spans to divs fixed it - it is probably something to do with the way that `display: block;`, `display: inline-block;` and `display: inline;` render differently from one another. Unless you override, `<span>` elements are rendered as `inline` - and float works a bit differently than when you are using `inline-block` elements or `block` elements, such as `<div>` tags.

Comment: Thanks @ Dan Heberden!                                                Display:none/block trick works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you better try something like this ?

```
<div style="float:left">left</div>
<div style="float:right">right</div>
```

I think this might work for you.

Keep me posted.

Comment: you're recommending inline css? **cold chill** (hoping it was for the short div not span example...)